# In C can you pass a macro with multiple values to a function

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I have a messaging function that takes a variable amount of arguments because it supports string formatting in the same way printf does. My plan was to then define message code and messages with a single `#define` and be able to call this function by passing it a single argument for something that is tightly related.

Here is the message macro:

```
#define MSG(a, b, ...) message(__FILE__, __LINE__, a, b, __VA_ARGS__);
```

And here is an example of the message code and string define:

```
#define MSG_INIT 0000,"%s INITIALIZED SUCCESSFULLY"
```

The issue is occurring when I try to make a call in the form of:

```
MSG(MSG_INIT);
```

My IDE is giving me an error along the lines of:

```
'Expands to message("file.c", 1, 0000, "INITIALIZED SUCCESSFULLY",);
```

where the last ',' is causing the issue.

I was expecting to see:

```
'Expands to message("file.c", 1, 0000, "INITIALIZED SUCCESSFULLY");
```

If I change the call to:

```
MSG(MSG_INIT,NULL);
```

All is good but I'd rather not pass the NULL because the point of the `MSG_INIT` define in the first place was to pass less parameters. There are messages that make use of the `__VA_ARGS__` (Example: `#define MSG_CONNECT 0001,"CONNECTION TO [%s] ESTABLISHED"` with matching call `MSG(MSG_CONEST, server_ip);`) so getting rid of that is not an option. I am just looking for the best way to fix this problem and I'm aware a lot of people suggest staying away from the preprocessor but this was the best solution I thought of.

Comment: Look at `__VA_OPT__(,)`

Comment: Another problem is that if you do `#define MSG_INIT 0000, "%s INITIALIZED SUCCESSFULLY"` then MSG_INIT is only one parameter.  So maybe you need `#define MSG(...) message(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm aware a lot of people suggest staying away from the preprocessor ...

I wonder why that is. Could it *possibly* be for the same reason you had to ask this question? :-)

Honestly, the pre-processor *should* be limited pretty much to including header files and doing conditional compilation. Anything else that it used to be used for, such as:

```
#define RC_OK    0
#define RC_NOMEM 1

#define HALF_OF(x) x / 2
```

is far better done with enumerations or functions.

The days of function-like macros should be put behind us, especially since modern compilers can quite easily out-optimise most hand-crafted code, and *without* subtle errors creeping in such as with that `HALF_OF` macro above (do *not* use it, I specifically made it buggy to illustrate a point).

It's really just a text substitution thing, one which understands the lexical elements, but not the full grammar of C. The fact that you have to perform what I call "macro gymnastics" to get it to do anything other than simple stuff is reason enough to steer clear. Use functions for this, it'll make your life a lot easier.

---

And apologies for not solving your *specific* issue, I just think *any* solution using the pre-processor is going to be half-baked at best. But there's plenty of precedent on SO for answering the question "How do I X?" with "Don't X, it's better to Y." Think of writing an accounting package in assembler, an operating system in object-oriented COBOL, or *anything* in Pascal :-)

But, if you *really* wanted to stick to macros against my advice, you could try starting with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MSG(fmtStr, ...) printf("%s:%d> " fmtStr, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define MSG_INIT "Initialised %s\n"
#define MSG_TERM "Terminated %s with values %d and %d\n"

int main(void) {
    MSG("%f\n", 42.3);
    MSG(MSG_INIT, "something");
    MSG(MSG_TERM, "something else", 7, 42);
}
```

I *think* that's portable, and it allow you to put the heavy lifting into `MSG` and using a separate format string and parameters for the rest of the stuff:

```
testprog.c:8> 42.300000
testprog.c:9> Initialised something
testprog.c:10> Terminated something else with values 7 and 42
```

Comment: Appreciate the advice. I'll probably end up avoiding the macro that defines two variables at once, however I have a follow up question. My main purpose for using the pre-processor macros are to pass the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` arguments for me. (I use this in more functions than just this message example) I am just using these to print the flow of the program in important functions. This is something I haven't seen discussed as often but would you suggest avoiding this as well and just passing those everytime I make a call to that function or is this more valid/safe use of the pre-processor?